# GHAssertThrowsSpecific cannot find type NSRangeException

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xcode4, gh-unit

I'm using Xcode 4 and GHUnit to write some unit tests for the first time.  All the advice appears to suggest going with GHUnit and not OCUnit.

I have a custom collection object called 'myList', and passing a message to get the selection at `index:-1`.  It therefore correctly throws an NSRangeException (from the underlying mutable array).

I'm struggling to catch this with a GHAssertThrowsSpecific assertion.

This following line of code will not compile saying 'Unknown type name 'NSRangeException'.

```
GHAssertThrowsSpecific(s = [myList selectionAtIndex:-1],
            NSRangeException, @"Should have thrown an NSRangeException", nil);
```

I am `#importing "Foundation/NSException.h"` where NSRangeException appears to be defined.  If I change it to:

```
GHAssertThrowsSpecific(s = [myList selectionAtIndex:-1],
            NSException, @"Should have thrown an NSException", nil);
```

then compiles fine and the assertion works, so its something to do with NSRangeException.

If I look in the headers, NSRangeException appears to be defined as a `NSString * const` in which case, how do I try to assert that I am expecting to catch it.

I'm obviously being quite dumb, as I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer to this one.

NSRangeException is indeed just a pointer to a string, which contains "NSRangeException".

Instead of using GHAssertThrowsSpecific, I should have been using GHAssertThrowsSpecificNamed, which takes an additional parameter of the string of the named exception, as follows:

```
GHAssertThrowsSpecificNamed(s = [myList selectionAtIndex:-1],
  NSException, NSRangeException, @"Should have thrown an NSRangeException", nil);
```

This works.